# Проблема с куками

Tags: php, cookie

Привет, по какой причине могут не устанавливаться куки? (никакого вывода до куков нет)
есть такой код, ума не приложу почему он не работает (может вы подскажете):

index.php

```
<?php var_dump ($_COOKIE); ?>
<form action="verify.php">
     <input name="pass" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

verify.php

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
     header('Location: index.php');
} else {
     setcookie ('welcome', $_POST['pass'], 1577836800);
     header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

где эта подлая ошибка?

`Я так предположил что нельзя поскавить куку перед хедером с редиректом ( location: anyurl.php ). Но тогда как правильно, скажем проверить пост данные, поставить куку и редиректнуть?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

method="post" в форме забыли

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!